# Connecting arcs on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to make a donut chart using the arc function in the HTML5 canvas. I am wanting to know how to use the lineTo function to connect two arcs together.

At the moment I have a pie chart which has fixed central x/y coords, so making the slices is easy as once the arc of each slice is done, the lineTo method simply uses the the fixed coords.

However with a ring/donut chart, I have two arcs, one with a smaller radius, but no idea how to connect the ends together without horrifically complicated trigonometry. Is there any way to get the 'start' and 'end' x/y coords of the arc?

I have a current hackyish 'solution' of simply drawing a smaller white circle over the pie chart to give the ring graph, but I want to know the answer to the question above.

Comment: Do you have a live example? or a fiddle?

Comment: You can stroke the arc with a big line width: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/19/. That basically draws the arc line, but because the width of the line is bigger than usual, it looks like a donut chart.

Comment: .lineWidth was not a viable option unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to remember a little trigonometry. If your center point is `x`, `y` and radius is `r`; then the coordinates on the circle at an angle `alpha` are:

```
pointX = x + Math.cos(alpha) * r;
pointY = y + Math.sin(alpha) * r;
```

And you have two of those angles, corresponding to the starting and the ending point.

Comment: Ha I'm embarrassed, such simple high school trig and I was going about it all wrong. Thanks, this has saved me much ache

Answer (score 0):

Why are you drawing arcs? Would'nt it be easier if you just draw the circle (or circles for the ring) and then draw radius?